# wildfly-logstash does not send logs to logstash

Tags: docker, jboss, logstash, wildfly, keycloak

I am using jboss/keycloak:11.0.2 and wildfly-logstash (https://github.com/kifj/wildfly-logstash) for transferring logs from wildfly to logstash. I met a problem when logstash up earlier than wildfly in this case logs do not send to logstash. Sometimes I see log like this
**myHost: Name or service not known**. Logger does not try to reconnect to myHost. An only restart helps. Wildfly startup script example:

```
embed-server --server-config=standalone-ha.xml --std-out=echo
module add --name=x1.wildfly-logstash --dependencies=org.jboss.logmanager,org.jboss.logging,javax.json.api --resources=/tmp/wildfly-logstash.jar

/subsystem=logging/custom-formatter=LOGSTASH-PATTERN:add(\
  class=net.logstash.logging.formatter.LogstashUtilFormatter,\
  module=x1.wildfly-logstash)

/subsystem=logging/custom-handler=LOGSTASH-SOCKET:add(level=DEBUG, class=net.logstash.logging.handler.SocketHandler,module=x1.wildfly-logstash,named-formatter=LOGSTASH-PATTERN,properties={hostname=myHost, port=${env.port}})

/subsystem=logging/async-handler=LOGSTASH-ASYNC:add(queue-length=512, subhandlers=[LOGSTASH-SOCKET])

/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:add-handler(name=LOGSTASH-ASYNC)

stop-embedded-server
```

Does anybody have an idea how to fix it?

Updated

```
08:42:15,759 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (CLI command executor) JBoss MSC version 1.4.11.Final
08:42:15,770 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (CLI command executor) JBoss Threads version 2.3.3.Final
08:42:15,913 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0049: Keycloak 11.0.2 (WildFly Core 12.0.3.Final) starting
08:42:16,080 INFO  [org.jboss.vfs] (MSC service thread 1-2) VFS000002: Failed to clean existing content for temp file provider of type temp. Enable DEBUG level log to find what caused this
08:42:17,124 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.12.1.Final
08:42:17,948 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
08:42:18,055 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
08:42:18,205 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYPAT0050: Keycloak cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
08:42:18,219 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
08:42:18,330 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
08:42:18,335 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: Keycloak 11.0.2 (WildFly Core 12.0.3.Final) started in 2661ms - Started 56 of 79 services (32 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
The batch executed successfully
08:42:18,661 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0050: Keycloak 11.0.2 (WildFly Core 12.0.3.Final) stopped in 15ms
08:42:20,127 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (CLI command executor) JBoss Modules version 1.10.1.Final
08:42:20,197 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (CLI command executor) JBoss MSC version 1.4.11.Final
08:42:20,206 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (CLI command executor) JBoss Threads version 2.3.3.Final
08:42:20,337 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: Keycloak 11.0.2 (WildFly Core 12.0.3.Final) starting
08:42:20,428 INFO  [org.jboss.vfs] (MSC service thread 1-2) VFS000002: Failed to clean existing content for temp file provider of type temp. Enable DEBUG level log to find what caused this
08:42:21,238 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.12.1.Final
08:42:22,373 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
08:42:22,526 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
08:42:22,671 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYPAT0050: Keycloak cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
08:42:22,685 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
08:42:22,772 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
08:42:22,773 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: Keycloak 11.0.2 (WildFly Core 12.0.3.Final) started in 2640ms - Started 56 of 86 services (39 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
The batch executed successfully
08:42:22,943 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0050: Keycloak 11.0.2 (WildFly Core 12.0.3.Final) stopped in 18ms
Executing cli script: /opt/jboss/startup-scripts/logstash-logging.cli
08:42:24,182 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (CLI command executor) JBoss Modules version 1.10.1.Final
08:42:24,233 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (CLI command executor) JBoss MSC version 1.4.11.Final
08:42:24,243 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (CLI command executor) JBoss Threads version 2.3.3.Final
08:42:24,360 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: Keycloak 11.0.2 (WildFly Core 12.0.3.Final) starting
08:42:24,449 INFO  [org.jboss.vfs] (MSC service thread 1-6) VFS000002: Failed to clean existing content for temp file provider of type temp. Enable DEBUG level log to find what caused this
08:42:25,020 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.12.1.Final
08:42:25,928 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
08:42:26,032 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
08:42:26,172 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYPAT0050: Keycloak cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
08:42:26,182 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
08:42:26,266 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
08:42:26,268 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: Keycloak 11.0.2 (WildFly Core 12.0.3.Final) started in 2081ms - Started 56 of 86 services (39 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
{"outcome" => "success"}
{"outcome" => "success"}
{"outcome" => "success"}
{"outcome" => "success"}
{"outcome" => "success"}
JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values:  -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.authz_drools_policy=enabled -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/jboss/keycloak

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server  -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.authz_drools_policy=enabled -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED

=========================================================================

08:42:27,098 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.10.1.Final
08:42:27,570 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.11.Final
08:42:27,577 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.3.3.Final
08:42:27,661 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: Keycloak 11.0.2 (WildFly Core 12.0.3.Final) starting
08:42:27,755 INFO  [org.jboss.vfs] (MSC service thread 1-8) VFS000002: Failed to clean existing content for temp file provider of type temp. Enable DEBUG level log to find what caused this
08:42:28,424 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.12.1.Final
08:42:29,278 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
08:42:29,367 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
08:42:29,403 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data/content/2f/209df99aaed727ee0550f516d84eeb80382895/content
08:42:29,646 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
08:42:29,667 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO version 3.8.1.Final
08:42:29,677 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.8.1.Final
08:42:29,739 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.18.Final
08:42:29,772 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 16 IO threads with 128 max task threads based on your 8 available processors
08:42:29,786 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) WFLYCLJG0001: Activating JGroups subsystem. JGroups version 4.2.4
08:42:29,794 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
08:42:29,832 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 42.2)
08:42:29,851 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.config.smallrye._private] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYCONF0001: Activating WildFly MicroProfile Config Subsystem
08:42:29,835 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.22.Final)
08:42:29,843 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
08:42:29,881 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = postgresql
08:42:29,815 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.12.1.Final
08:42:29,972 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
08:42:29,974 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.health.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) WFLYHEALTH0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Health Subsystem
08:42:29,974 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) WFLYMETRICS0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Metrics Subsystem
08:42:29,978 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
08:42:29,969 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
08:42:29,891 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
08:42:30,107 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.3.Final-redhat-00005
08:42:30,164 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.1.3.Final starting
08:42:30,204 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
08:42:30,244 WARN  [org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYCLWEBUT0007: No routing provider found for default-server; using legacy provider based on static configuration
08:42:30,251 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
08:42:30,397 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 32 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
08:42:30,400 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 128 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
08:42:30,498 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/opt/jboss/keycloak/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
08:42:30,509 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
08:42:30,512 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
08:42:30,661 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0006: Undertow AJP listener ajp listening on 0.0.0.0:8009
08:42:30,662 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 0.0.0.0:8080
08:42:30,673 INFO  [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) MODCLUSTER000001: Initializing mod_cluster version 1.4.1.Final
08:42:30,711 INFO  [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) MODCLUSTER000032: Listening to proxy advertisements on /224.0.1.105:23364
08:42:30,883 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
08:42:31,004 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYPAT0050: Keycloak cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
08:42:31,036 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS]
08:42:31,036 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
08:42:31,060 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
08:42:31,100 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments
08:42:31,122 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "keycloak-server.war" (runtime-name: "keycloak-server.war")
08:42:31,268 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 0.0.0.0:8443
08:42:32,118 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JGRP000015: the send buffer of socket ManagedMulticastSocketBinding was set to 1.00MB, but the OS only allocated 212.99KB
08:42:32,118 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JGRP000015: the receive buffer of socket ManagedMulticastSocketBinding was set to 20.00MB, but the OS only allocated 212.99KB
08:42:32,119 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JGRP000015: the send buffer of socket ManagedMulticastSocketBinding was set to 1.00MB, but the OS only allocated 212.99KB
08:42:32,119 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JGRP000015: the receive buffer of socket ManagedMulticastSocketBinding was set to 25.00MB, but the OS only allocated 212.99KB
08:42:32,587 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.logging.handler."org.wildfly.logging.handler.LOGSTASH-SOCKET": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.logging.handler."org.wildfly.logging.handler.LOGSTASH-SOCKET": Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: myHost: Name or service not known
    at org.jboss.as.logging@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.logging.handlers.SocketHandlerResourceDefinition$WildFlyClientSocketFactory.getAddress(SocketHandlerResourceDefinition.java:448)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.15.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.SocketHandler.<init>(SocketHandler.java:185)
    at org.jboss.as.logging@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.logging.handlers.SocketHandlerResourceDefinition$1$2$1.start(SocketHandlerResourceDefinition.java:242)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: myHost: Name or service not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1515)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1248)
    at org.jboss.as.network@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.network.OutboundSocketBinding.getResolvedDestinationAddress(OutboundSocketBinding.java:159)
    at org.jboss.as.logging@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.logging.handlers.SocketHandlerResourceDefinition$WildFlyClientSocketFactory.getAddress(SocketHandlerResourceDefinition.java:446)
    ... 10 more

08:42:35,158 INFO  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) 81aea0e8fa13: no members discovered after 3007 ms: creating cluster as coordinator
08:42:36,214 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0273: Excluded subsystem webservices via jboss-deployment-structure.xml does not exist.
08:42:36,687 INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) KC-SERVICES0001: Loading config from standalone.xml or domain.xml
08:42:36,786 WARN  [org.keycloak.common.Profile] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Deprecated feature enabled: upload_scripts
08:42:36,786 WARN  [org.keycloak.common.Profile] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Preview feature enabled: scripts
08:42:36,972 INFO  [org.keycloak.url.DefaultHostnameProviderFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Frontend: http://localhost:8100/auth, Admin: <frontend>, Backend: <request>
08:42:37,203 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0002: Started realmRevisions cache from keycloak container
08:42:37,206 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0002: Started userRevisions cache from keycloak container
08:42:37,211 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0002: Started authorizationRevisions cache from keycloak container
08:42:37,213 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.infinispan.DefaultInfinispanConnectionProviderFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Node name: 81aea0e8fa13, Site name: null
08:42:40,226 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: keycloak-default
    ...]
08:42:40,330 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.17.Final}
08:42:40,332 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
08:42:40,566 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.5.Final}
08:42:40,849 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
08:42:41,249 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08:42:41,258 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@210c2412
08:42:41,267 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Envers integration enabled? : true
08:42:42,324 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.beans] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH10005002: No explicit CDI BeanManager reference was passed to Hibernate, but CDI is available on the Hibernate ClassLoader.
08:42:42,426 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.20.Final
08:42:44,259 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
08:42:45,309 INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) KC-SERVICES0006: Importing users from '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json'
08:42:45,517 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) KC-SERVICES0104: Not creating user admin. It already exists.
08:42:45,567 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
08:42:45,569 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSecurityHeadersFilter from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
08:42:45,570 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
08:42:45,571 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.keycloak.services.resources.ThemeResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
08:42:45,571 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.keycloak.services.resources.JsResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
08:42:45,571 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.RobotsResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
08:42:45,571 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) RESTEASY002210: Adding provider singleton org.keycloak.services.util.ObjectMapperResolver from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
08:42:45,572 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.WelcomeResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
08:42:45,572 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.AdminRoot from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
08:42:45,572 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.RealmsResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
08:42:45,687 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/auth' for server 'default-server'
08:42:45,816 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "logging"),
    ("socket-handler" => "LOGSTASH-SOCKET")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.logging.handler.\"org.wildfly.logging.handler.LOGSTASH-SOCKET\"" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: myHost: Name or service not known
    Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: myHost: Name or service not known"}}
08:42:45,831 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "keycloak-server.war" (runtime-name : "keycloak-server.war")
08:42:45,832 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service org.wildfly.logging.handler."org.wildfly.logging.handler.LOGSTASH-SOCKET": Failed to start service

08:42:45,902 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
08:42:45,906 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: Keycloak 11.0.2 (WildFly Core 12.0.3.Final) started (with errors) in 19124ms - Started 732 of 1039 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 707 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
08:42:45,908 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
08:42:45,908 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't need to install that module to achieve this. WildFly has a built-in `json-formatter` and `socket-handler`. In fact a lot of the code looks like it was taken from the JBoss Log Manager :) The one difference is the fields. With the below example I'll just show you an option you can use.

```
embed-server --server-config=standalone-ha.xml --std-out=echo

/subsystem=logging/json-formatter=LOG-STASH:add(key-overrides={timestamp=@timestamp,message=@message,logger-name=@source,host-name=@source_host}, exception-output-type=formatted)

/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding=log-stash:add(host=localhost, port=${env.port})
/subsystem=logging/socket-handler=LOGSTASH-SOCKET:add(named-formatter=LOG-STASH, outbound-socket-binding-ref=log-stash, level=DEBUG)

/subsystem=logging/async-handler=LOGSTASH-ASYNC:add(queue-length=512, subhandlers=[LOGSTASH-SOCKET])

/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:add-handler(name=LOGSTASH-ASYNC)

stop-embedded-server
```

The `socket-handler` will attempt to reconnect if a connection fails. You can use the `block-on-reconnect=true` attribute if you want to block until the connection can be reset.

Comment: I tried with block-on-reconnect = true it does not try to reconnect. Firstly I start WildFly then logstash. On WildFly I see follow logs `MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.logging.handler." Org.wildfly.logging.handler.LOGSTASH-SOCKET ": myHost: Name or service not known` then appears log `{"WFLYCTL0080 : Failed services "=> {" org.wildfly.logging.handler. \ "Org.wildfly.logging.handler.LOGSTASH-SOCKET \" "=>" Failed to start service` .

Comment: I start logstash after WildFly is fully started

Comment: This is configuration: `/subsystem=logging/socket-handler=LOGSTASH-SOCKET:add(block-on-reconnect=true, named-formatter=LOG-STASH, outbound-socket-binding-ref=log-stash, level=DEBUG)`

Comment: That seems a bit backwards. You should definitely start Logstash first, then WildFly. I'm not too sure from that message what the issue might be.

Comment: It is possible to configure WildFly to try to connect to logstash, even if this one is unavailable?

Comment: Can you share more of the log? I just tested it with starting WildFly first then just an echo server and that worked for me.

Comment: Perfect thanks! It looks like it's an issue with the host name `myHost`. I just tried on `localhost` which resolves for me. You'd have to use a resolvable host name.