# Wildfly json log formatter dynamic configuration not applied

Tags: json, logging, configuration, logstash, wildfly

**Wildfly** 20 is connected with a **Logstash** instance listening on tcp port 5300:

**logstash.conf:**

```
input {
 tcp {
    codec => json
    port => "5300"
  }
}

output {
  stdout {}
}
```

Making use of its built-in json logging capabilities with socket connection, as outpointed in [wildfly-logstash does not send logs to logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65919433), Wildfly is configured on the **Wildfly CLI**, entering the following sequence of statements (that end up in standalone.xml automatically):

```
/subsystem=logging/json-formatter=LOG-STASH:add(key-overrides={timestamp=@timestamp,message=@message,logger-name=@source,host-name=@source_host}, exception-output-type=formatted)

/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding=log-stash:add(host=localhost, port=8000)
/subsystem=logging/socket-handler=LOGSTASH-SOCKET:add(named-formatter=LOG-STASH, outbound-socket-binding-ref=log-stash, level=DEBUG)

/subsystem=logging/async-handler=LOGSTASH-ASYNC:add(queue-length=512, subhandlers=[LOGSTASH-SOCKET])

/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:add-handler(name=LOGSTASH-ASYNC)
```

It produces log statements on standard out of the logstash node, as e.g.:

```
{
          "level" => "DEBUG",
           "host" => "gateway",
      "processId" => 14972,
       "sequence" => 34696,
       "@version" => "1",
        "@source" => "com.myapplication.TaskService",
   "@source_host" => "device-01",
     "threadName" => "EJB default - 6",
       "threadId" => 215,
"loggerClassName" => "org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger",
            "mdc" => {},
            "ndc" => "",
           "port" => 64210,
    "processName" => "jboss-modules.jar",
     "@timestamp" => 2021-03-31T14:10:19.869Z,
       "@message" => "task execution successfull: MailDaemon"
}
```

That is only **half way to the goal**, required is another set of attribute names (of the individual json log message) to fit in our enterprise logstash instances.
Especially, neither "host-name" nor "logger-name" are written, although configured; instead "@source_host" and @source are logged.

Further adaption of the log-formatter LOG-STASH partially succeeds.

```
1) /subsystem=logging/json-formatter=LOG-STASH:write-attribute(name="meta-data",value={service="myapplication-api", serviceversion="1.1.0", instanceId="myapplication-api-1.1.0"})
2) /subsystem=logging/json-formatter=LOG-STASH:write-attribute(name="key-overrides",value=[severity=level,timestamp=@timestamp,message=msg,logger-name=@source,host-name=@source_host])
```

Further simplifaction results in attribute stored, but not applied:

```
3) /subsystem=logging/json-formatter=LOG-STASH:write-attribute(name="key-overrides",value={"level"="severity"})
4) /subsystem=logging/json-formatter=LOG-STASH:read-attribute(name="key-overrides")
```

1. works and meta data are added. 2. and 3. bring no results. 4. prints out like

   ```
    INFO  [org.jboss.as.cli.CommandContext] {
        "outcome" => "success",
        "result" => {"level" => "severity"}
    }
    {
        "outcome" => "success",
        "result" => {"level" => "severity"}
    }
   ```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What keys do you want printed for logger-name and host-name? You've mapped it as follows `logger-name=@source,host-name=@source_host` which are both in your JSON output.

Comment: ```@source``` and ```@source_host``` are default property names printed out in Wildfly logging (of a single line). By configuration I wanted to "rename" the property names. E.g. "logger-name" instead of "@source".
Or "severity" instead of the default name "level", refer LOG-STASH:write-attribute(name="key-overrides",value={"level"="severity"})
Neither putting the "new" property names on the left side nor of the right side of the assignment works.

Comment: `logger-name` and `host-name` are the default keys. In your add you're overriding them to `@source` and `@source_host` so you'd want to leave that off. Overriding `level` to `severity` should work fine as well.

Comment: As a follow up, can you post what you want the JSON to look like? That would help me understand the final goal.

Comment: The following CLI command worked for me: ```/subsystem=logging/json-formatter=LOG-STASH:write-attribute(name="key-overrides",value={"level"="severity","sequence"="trace","thread-id"="pid","logger-class-name"="class","thread-name"="thread"})```.

Comment: Widlfy logging is not consistent. There was a discrepancy between ```standalone.xml``` and ```logging.properties```. I cleared the logging keys on both files. Still there is a key ```@timestamp``` and ```@version``` in the produced log output hanging arround.

Comment: If you use CLI they should be consistent. You've got those two values added in your `meta-data`. If you execute `/subsystem=logging/json-formatter=LOG-STASH:undefine-attribute(name=meta-data)` that should remove those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the above setup the following Wildfly CLI command sucessfully renames the wanted keys' default values:

```
/subsystem=logging/json-formatter=LOG-STASH:write-attribute(name="key-overrides",value={"level"="severity","sequence"="trace","thread-id"="pid","logger-class-name"="class","thread-name"="thread"})
```

These settings end up in `standalone.xml` and `logging.properties` in the same folder on disk.
During my work there was a discrepancy between configured keys in both files.

Be aware that camel case key names like `threadId` produce a configuration error. You have to use `thread-id` instead. I found this by inspection of the JBoss logging library, i.e. looking on the Java source code.

The produced logging output is e.g.

```
{
               "pid" => 212,
           "message" => "Synchronizaing finished in 0ms",
          "@version" => "1",
        "loggerName" => "com.myapp.Cache",
        "@timestamp" => 2021-04-08T13:49:00.178Z,
              "port" => 59182,
       "processName" => "jboss-modules.jar",
             "trace" => 4245,
              "host" => "gateway",
          "severity" => "DEBUG",
         "processId" => 10536,
               "mdc" => {},
          "hostName" => "host-alpha",
         "timestamp" => "2021-04-08T15:49:00.176+02:00",
             "class" => "org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger",
               "ndc" => "",
            "thread" => "EJB default - 7"
}
```

What would be nice still, is to have fields `mdc` and `ndc` deprived of the output.