# Keycloak ERROR_LOG to log file

Tags: logging, keycloak

I have a problem with configuration for save Keycloak ERROR_LOG to custom file. In /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/log see only server.log.
How can I save a error log to custom file?

Keycloak is deployed from Docker Hub to k8s.

Many thanks for tips

Comment: Why you are not checking stdout/stderr of the container?

Comment: Yes that's works fine but I would like to save the file for parsing in logstash (kibana). Logstash is like side container with Keycloak and this error log will be on shared folder between.

An stdout/stderr would be enough for me but when I change that output to json format but message of this log is not in json.

FORMAT:
type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=local, clientId=oauth2-keycloak, userId=null, ipAddress=10.36.4.197


That's why I need a log file with this login error. for parsing with Logstash.

Comment: IMHO it is overkill: I would use `logspout` to collect container stdout/stderr or docker log driver on the container level and then I'll point it to the `logstash` for processing.

Comment: You that's true.
I send log to logstash via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65919433/wildfly-logstash-does-not-send-logs-to-logstash

The connection works and now it's just about setting up a logstash.
Many thanks @JanGaraj